Microsoft ASP.NET Core Identity framework crashing on "Release" configuration?
I'm building a Blazor WASM frontend that talks to a ASP.NET Core Web API (which communicates with a SQL database). I've got it all setup and it's working great in "Debug" configuration on my machine. I then deployed both to Azure using Static web app for the frontend and a web app for the backend.
I then had to realize, that if I try to register a new user, the app would throw this error code in the browsers console (happens both in the deployed version, but also when I'm running the app locally in release configuration):
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ExpectedJsonTokens Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: ExpectedJsonTokens Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: ExpectedJsonTokens LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& , ExceptionResource , Byte , ReadOnlySpan`1 )
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[ASBNApp.Frontend.Model.Identity.RegisterAccountBadRequest, ASBNApp.Frontend, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& , JsonReaderException )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[ASBNApp.Frontend.Model.Identity.RegisterAccountBadRequest, ASBNApp.Frontend, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1[[ASBNApp.Frontend.Model.Identity.RegisterAccountBadRequest, ASBNApp.Frontend, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].Deserialize(Utf8JsonReader& , ReadStack& )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[RegisterAccountBadRequest](ReadOnlySpan`1 , JsonTypeInfo`1 , Nullable`1 )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[RegisterAccountBadRequest](ReadOnlySpan`1 , JsonTypeInfo`1 )
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[RegisterAccountBadRequest](String , JsonSerializerOptions )
   at ASBNApp.Frontend.Pages.Register.HandleRegistering()
   at ASBNApp.Frontend.Pages.Register.<BuildRenderTree>b__0_6()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at MudBlazor.MudBaseButton.OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs ev)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task , ComponentState )

I'm using the Identity package to implement authentication, this is the exact one: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
I'm think the error is caused by my frontend (because I can still register using the Swagger UI), however I cannot figure out where the issue could originate from.
Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?
All code is available open source here, just in case that helps (ignore the ASBNApp folder, that one is legacy): https://github.com/mr-woodapple/ASBNApp/tree/origin/feature/%2345_DatabaseAndCoreIdentity

Hi mr-woodapple, usually this error is because the response data is not  json type , maybe due to 401 or other errors, the returned data may be html.

From your error message, we can find HandleRegistering method in your Register.razor page, and please set breakpoint in Line 126, and debug it step by step(you can use console.writeline or other ways), then we can find the root cause.

Okay, I managed to solve this issue with the help of a colleague. There were two things wrong, not sure if the first one has any relevance to this.

My API wasn't picking up the connection string for the database - the value set for "Default" in my appsettings (and Azure Environment Variables) wasn't picked up - don't know why. I solved this by simply adding another string in "ConnectionStrings", that new one was picked up fine.
The api wasn't added as a user to my database. So the api could technically access the database server (setup through EntraID), but was refused any access by the database itself. The solution was  to run the query you can find in the second step here (I did that using Azure Data Studio, but you can use whatever you want to access your database): Microsoft Docs

Hope that helps anyone in the future, thanks for anyone trying to help!
(The error you see in my original question is a result from the IIS server returning an html doc containing an error message - without any experience, that didn't help me at all.)
